# Managing and Binding Usercontrols

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls

I am quite new to WPF and now am encountered a scenario were i couldn't find any effective solution.
In my project i have many viewmodels and usercontrols. The main window is splited into two and in the left hand side i display usercontrols according to the current viewmodel everythis works fine. The problem starts when i wanted to display a second usercontrol in the right hand side according to what user selected in the left hand side. The user control has many text boxes and Combo box. how will i bind this data from the cosequtive view model?

```
//mainwindow.xaml
<Window.resources>
<Datatemplate Datatype={x:Type vm:Viewmodel1}>
<loc:Usercontrol1/> // in the left hand side
</DataTemplate>
<Datatemplate Datatype={x:Type vm:Viewmodel2}>
<loc:Usercontrol2/> // in the lefthand side
</DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
...
<Grid Grid.Column="0">
<ContentControl Content={Binding CurrentViewModel}/>
</Grid>
<Grid Grid.Column="1">
<Grid.Resources>
 <Datatemplate Datatype={x:Type vm:Viewmodel1}>
<loc:Usercontrol3 NameDp={Binding Name}/> // in the right hand side
</DataTemplate>
<Datatemplate Datatype={x:Type vm:Viewmodel2}>
<loc:Usercontrol3/> // in the rightthand side
</DataTemplate>
</Grid.Resources>
</Grid>

// Usercontrol3.xaml
<Grid>
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=NameDp, ElementName=UserControl3}" />
</Grid> 
// UserControl3.cs
public static readonly DependencyProperty NameUCProperty  =DependencyProperty.Register("NameDp", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl3), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(NamePropertyChanged));
public string NameDp
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(NameUCProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(NameUCProperty, value);
        }
    }

//ViewModel
Public Name {get;set;}
```

In each viewmodels i get data from the Database and i would like to Bind those data to the Usercontrols in the right hand side according to the user selection. How do i Bind these data?
Is this the right approch or am i completly wrong?

Comment: You only have to define your data templates one time, not multiple times.  From the source of the binding, a search is performed up the logical tree to find the first data template that matches the data type of the binding object.  Other than that, this looks correct.  Is it not working?

Comment: @Will As i mentioned I wanted to load the left hand side first and later when the user select something i wanted to Open the next usercontrol in the right hand side. if i put together how will i indicate that which on should show first and were.

Comment: @Will Left hand side work perfectly. This way even am able to load the user control on right hand side. The realy problem is the second set of usercontrols am not able to bind. Textbox is always blank. which am not understanding

Comment: Well, depends.  "When the user select something" meaning what?  If UC1 shows a list of items, for example, and you want UC2 to display the selected item... that's easy.  In UC1, bind the SelectedItem property of the list to a public DependencyProperty on the UserControl (yes, codebehind). Then, in the Window, bind the second ContentControl to that public DependencyProperty.

Comment: @Will Yes left hand side is always list and when user select an item from the list. The details of the item should be displayed in the UC2. Cureently when the user double click , i have implemented a Command in the viewmodel and send the Selected item as a Command parameter to search in the database to get more details. Once i have that i would like to bind from there directly to Usercontrol. If possible. I am not sure how this has to be done. Small psuedo code will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

That's definitely one way to do that.  For me, I'd organize things this way.  I've got a prototype around here that demonstrates how this stuff works...

First, our MainWindow

```
<Window x:Class="WpfUserControlsBindingListeningNotMuchHere.MainWindow"
        xmlns:t="clr-namespace:WpfUserControlsBindingListeningNotMuchHere"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:ms="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="350"
        Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <t:ViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <t:UserControl1 x:Name="uc1"
                        Items="{Binding Items}"
                        Selected="{Binding Selected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <t:UserControl2 Grid.Column="1"
                        DataContext="{Binding Result}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Note *uc1*.  It takes in a list and exposes the selected item.  These are all bound to the ViewModel.  Properties `Items` and `Selected` are *DependencyProperties* I have defined on the UserControl.  I can show the code if you want, but it should be understandable without.  (The `Mode=TwoWay` could be done away with if I tweaked the DP definition.)

In the ViewModel, I listen for changes to `Selected` and do my work accordingly.

```
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private object _selected;

    private object _result;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ObservableCollection<object> Items { get; private set; }

    public object Selected
    {
        get { return this._selected; }
        set
        {
            if (_selected == value)
                return;
            this._selected = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Selected"));
        }
    }

    public object Result
    {
        get { return this._result; }
        set
        {
            if (_result == value )
            return;
            this._result = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Result"));
        }
    }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<object>();
        Items.Add(1);
        Items.Add("hello");
        Items.Add(3.0d);
        PropertyChanged += OnPropertyChanged;
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName != "Selected")
            return; 

        //DO MASSIVE WORK HER ON BACKGROUND THREAD OR SOMETHING LOL
        Result = "OMG THIS TOOK A LONG TIME, " + Selected.ToString();
    }
}
```

So, I'm simply watching for a change to Selected, at which point I do my work (business logic) and expose the result within another property.  This is then bound to my second UserControl in the UI.

As I said, the UC code is trivial...

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfUserControlsBindingListeningNotMuchHere.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             x:Name="root">
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items, ElementName=root}"
             SelectedItem="{Binding Selected, ElementName=root}" />
</UserControl>
```

and in the codebehind (OMG CODEBEHIND LOOK OUT EVIL)

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    #region Items
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Items",
        typeof(IEnumerable<object>),
        typeof(UserControl1),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public IEnumerable<object> Items
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable<object>)GetValue(ItemsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsProperty, value); }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Selected
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Selected",
        typeof(object),
        typeof(UserControl1),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public object Selected
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(SelectedProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedProperty, value); }
    }
    #endregion

    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

and

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfUserControlsBindingListeningNotMuchHere.UserControl2"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
</UserControl>
```

No codebehind on this one.

Comment: I will try this out, it will be really great if you could put the usercontrol code too.

Comment: I tried this whole day, but with my requirement its not working. the list is always binding but the second set is not binding. My second set of usercontrol is not just one textbox, but its like a form with many labels and comboboxes etc

Comment: @user1767798: Notice the second user control.  The "selected" item is binding to the DataContext of this control.  Within this user controls, the individual form controls should be bound to properties of this object.  It's just like binding to properties of the ViewModel in the window.  Not sure why you are having issues, as it is trivial...

Comment: @ Thank you for your time and advice, i could see that my viewmodel property is getting the data but its not displying. But anyway i solved this by removing usercontrol and putting them in a resouce dictionary and displayed according to current view model. its working perfectly.